# How to reset the time value of setTimeout() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout

I want to display an alert() box, just 10 seconds after user stops writting in a textbox.

I used following javascript code to open alertbox -

```
function txtkeyup(e){
  setTimeout(function () {
    alert('submit?');
  }, 10000);
  return true;
}
```

and the HTML code is -

```
<input type='textbox' name='searchquery' value='' onkeyup='return txtkeyup();'>
```

Now the browser is giving alertbox, 10 seconds after every onkeyup event in  the inputbox.
To make only one request, i have to reset the setTimeout() timer on every keyup event so the alertbox will be display if user doesnt press a button for 10 seconds.

How can reset the timer of previously called 'setTimeout()' in javascript? Please guide me..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`var myTimeout = setTimeout ( ...)`

to clear it simply write
`clearTimeout(myTimeout);`

Comment: You can enclose text between backticks (`) to format it as code (I've done it for you on this answer).